# FMResultset to Nsarray

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

I have 2035 object in my sqlite database. And I am trying to show them in tableview.I am adding objects to `NSMutablearray` with this code.

```
FMResultSet *rs = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT name,tel1 FROM KartDB"];
    KartList *kart = [[KartList alloc] init];
        while ([rs next]) {
            kart.name = [rs stringForColumn:@"name"];
            kart.tel1 = [rs stringForColumn:@"tel1"];

            [_customers addObject:kart];
        }
```

I put breakpoint to `[_customers addObject:kart];` line. Its replacing all values every loop.What should I need for this.

Thanks.

Comment: I think `KartList *kart = [[KartList alloc] init];` should be inside while loop. And where are you incrementing the pointer to `rs` variable ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same `kart` object each time, and changing its values and adding to the array, it will always add the same Object and at the end you`ll have the same object 2035 times with latest values,

You must create `kart` object for each row

```
FMResultSet *rs = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT name,tel1 FROM KartDB"];

    while ([rs next]) {
        // Inside loop
        KartList *kart = [[KartList alloc] init];
        kart.name = [rs stringForColumn:@"name"];
        kart.tel1 = [rs stringForColumn:@"tel1"];

        [_customers addObject:kart];
    }
```

Comment: Ok That works.Thanks and I tried 
[_customers addobject:[rs resultDictionary]];
That works too.